# Strange Issues with javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, gradle, jira-rest-java-api

Today I updated a command line application to Spring Boot 3.0.6

I receive a `BeanCreationException` exception when starting the application. Reason is

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder
```

which is needed internaly by `com.atlassian.jira.rest.client.api.JiraRestClient`. In IDEA, when I search for `javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder` I do not find any class.

So I included

```
implementation 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1.1'
```

in my Gradle build. Now I receive a

```
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: ClassCastException: attempting to cast
jar:file:/XXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.1.1/d3466bc9321fe84f268a1adb3b90373fc14b0eb5/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class to
jar:file:/XXX/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/javax.ws.rs/javax.ws.rs-api/2.1.1/d3466bc9321fe84f268a1adb3b90373fc14b0eb5/javax.ws.rs-api-2.1.1.jar!/javax/ws/rs/ext/RuntimeDelegate.class
```

both lines/files are identically.

Things I tried so far:

- Checking for different versions of `javax.ws.rs` with `gradlew dependencies`
- Clean build

Has anyone an idea how to solve this and why is UriBuilder gone at all?

Comment: Should not the artifact name for Spring Boot 3+ be 'jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api' and not 'javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api'?

Comment: This JAR doesn't contain `javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder`, it contains `jakarta.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder` - therefor the dependency is not fulfilled.

Comment: Not necessarily, for version 2.1.x the package name is javax.ws.rs.core, even though the artifact name starts with 'jakarta'. Please check https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.ws.rs/jakarta.ws.rs-api/2.1.4
Therefore it might be suitable for the requirement from JiraRestClient.

Comment: @Albina I imported `jakarta.ws.rs:jakarta.ws.rs-api` and looked into it, there is no `javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder`, there is only a `jakarta.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder`

Comment: But maybe is your first comment the answer: I am not able to update to Spring Boot 3.x until JiraRestClient upgraded to `jakarta.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is I think according to the Spring-Boot Release Notes (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes), it is clearly mentioned it has been migrated from Java EE to Jakarta EE APIs (in this case javax.ws.rs and your Spring-Boot version is Spring Boot 3.0.6).

> Spring Boot 3.0 has migrated from Java EE to Jakarta EE APIs for all dependencies. Wherever possible, Jakarta EE 10 compatible dependencies have been chosen, including:

It has further included the compatible version to use is `Jakarta WS RS 3.1`

Comment: Understood, thanks a lot. This means I have to stick to 2.x until JiraRestClient upgraded to `jakarta.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder`

Comment: The corresponding issue is https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/JRJC-262

Comment: Yes, either you need to either adjust your Spring Boot version or use the compatible  Jakarta WS RS or jakarta.ws.rs dependency type against the Spring Boot version to make the UriBuilder available in your classpath :)

Answer (score 6):

I tested it In Spring boot 3.0.6

build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.atlassian.jira:jira-rest-java-client-core:5.2.5") {
        exclude(group = "org.glassfish.jersey.core", module = "jersey-common")
    }
    implementation("org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common:2.27")
    compileOnly("io.atlassian.fugue:fugue:5.0.0")
}
```

First, exclude `org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common` from `jira-rest-java-client-core`

Then, make version of `org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-common` down to 2.27 which has `javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api`

Jira api doesn't update javax to jakarta yet, so we can solve like above.

Comment: If you follow https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/browse/JRJC-262, you will see my solution. But of course, your solution is much better, for me the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with it, you can set the `jersey.version` property in your `build.gradle` or `pom.xml` to `2.35`.